# Get content of an iframe after it loads with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve the fallowing goal.I want by the click of a button to get the domain name entered in one input and load it into an iframe. What i have trouble with is after i load the specific site in the iframe how can i get the DOM of the loaded site in the iframe ? I need to save the exact path of an element of my choosing from the newly loaded site in the iframe by clicking on it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `<iframe>`'s contents via the `contentDocument` property.

```
var iFrameContent = $('myIFrame')[0].contentDocument;
$(iFrameContent).find('.mySelector').text();
```

I should also point out accessing the `<iframe>`'s contents can only be done if the `src` of the `<iframe>` is from the same domain as your script. If the `src` of the `<iframe>` is from any other domain, the browser will deny access to the `<iframe>`contents.

This is a [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) consideration.

**UPDATE:**

To get around the CORS limitation, you'll have to write a server-side proxy for the URL that is the `src` of the `<iframe>` (and it could be pretty simple).

If I were to do something like this in ASP.Net (as an example), I would write a web service that:

1. takes the actual URL as a `String` parameter.
2. Uses the `HTTPWebRequest` object (or similar) to get the URL contents.
3. Return it back to the browser.

Then you could set your `<iframe>` `src` to "`http://mysite.com/getURLService?url=www.lalala.com`" and get the contents because the contents are now delivered by "http://mysite.com".

Comment: Well... that's the problem,it is not with the same domain name, i am doing that on my domain and i load another site in the iframe ... like www.lalala.com and i want to get it's DOM , not mine... is there anyway that can happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You use `.contents()`

`like $("iframe").contents().find();` etc

Comment: For the record you can use contents() to get the contents of an iframe. It says so in the jQuery docs and I have done it myself many times.